# can anyone explain the FBX format for me?

Tags: graphics, data-structures, dataformat, fbx

i use notepad++ to see the data structure of FBX model but i have some problems understanding it. Here is some info of a cube(side = 10) located in (0,0,0), can anyone tell me what do these members mean? THANKS!

```
Vertices: *24 {
a: -5,-5,0,5,-5,0,-5,5,0,5,5,0,-5,-5,10,5,-5,10,-5,5,10,5,5,10
} 
PolygonVertexIndex: *36 {
a: 0,2,-4,3,1,-1,4,5,-8,7,6,-5,0,1,-6,5,4,-1,1,3,-8,7,5,-2,3,2,-7,6,7,-4,2,0,-5,4,6,-3
} 
Edges: *18 {
a: 0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,16,19,20,25,26,32
} 
Normals: *108 {
a: 0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,-        1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-   1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0
} 

UV: *24 {
a: 0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1
} 
UVIndex: *36 {
a: 9,11,10,10,8,9,8,9,11,11,10,8,4,5,7,7,6,4,0,1,3,3,2,0,4,5,7,7,6,4,0,1,3,3,2,0
}
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation can be found here: https://banexdevblog.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/a-quick-tutorial-about-the-fbx-ascii-format/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even with no knowledge of the FBX format you can at least make some very reasonable guesses:

1. The 24 values under `Vertices` are the 8 vertices of the cube (with 3 values representing one vertex).
2. The 36 values under `PolygonVertexIndex` are the vertex indices (referencing the values from `Vertices`) for the 12 triangles making up the 6 faces of the cube.
3. The 24 values under `Edges` are the vertex indices of the 12 edges of the cube.
4. The 108 values under `Normals` are the 36 normals for each of the triangle corners of the 12 triangles (with 3 values representing one normal vector).
5. The 24 values under `UV` are 12 texture coordinates (with 2 values representing one texture coordinate pair).
6. The 36 values under `UVIndex` are the texture coordinate indices (referencing the values from `UV`) for the 36 triangle corners of the cube.

I think these assumptions are quite reasonable, though I'm not sure why the `PolygonVertexIndex` array contains negative values (it seems every third index of each triangle is negative). Maybe to indicate the last index of a polygon, so you can have polygons which need not be triangles.

Comment: yeah the "normals" are normals for the three vertices of 12 faces. But isn't the a vertex's normal computed by adding the normals of the faces connected with the vertex and then normalizing? I got quite confused with the normal of a vertex and the normal of a face.

Comment: @yvetterowe The normals can be computed anyway you want and for a cube it is no good idea to average a vertex's adjacent face normals. The format seems to store a normal for each triangle corner (therefore 36 normals) and not for each triangle or for each vertex. This way the normals can be whatever they want (per-vertex, per-face or something in between), introducing duplicate normals as neccessary.

Comment: regarding `Edges`, These are **not** vertex indices's, They are direct references to the PolygonVertexIndex array. Each edge is defined by that vertex and the next one in that face (if the index is < 0, it wraps around to the first index in that polygon). (I found this while writing an importer, if you load these values as edge-index-pairs you end up with scrambled edges all over the mesh)

Answer (score 11):

> I think these assumptions are quite reasonable, though I'm not sure
>   why the PolygonVertexIndex array contains negative values (it seems
>   every third index of each triangle is negative). Maybe to indicate the
>   last index of a polygon, so you can have polygons which need not be
>   triangles.

The one with the negative value represents the last vertex indeed.

To find out witch vertex this is, you have to negate it and subtract 1 from that value.

For example, `-4` represents `3 ((-4)*(-1) - 1)`

Comment: And this makes perfect sense, Thanks Autodesk... I guess we have to deal with this.

Comment: Now that I think about it the -1 is smart because otherwise you have a problem with index 0!

Comment: indeed, it is, is the last one on the polygon. The FBX can define multivertex polygons, and uses the (-N-1) to show wich one is the end.

Answer (score 10):

The negative vertex index indicates the end of the polygon. You can bitwise negate the negative index, to get the positive one.

In c this would be

```
posIndex = ~negIndex;
```