# Why do I get anormal characters when I open a FBX file with notepad?

Tags: fbx

I need to get more information about FBX files.

Firstly, when I open an FBX file with notepad, I see many anormal characters. Some files look normal. But how can I fix the problem? And if you can help me, you can explain or link an FBX loader?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think will work? Have you looked for or found a library capable of loading the file format?

Comment: I searched libraries, But i couldn't found any free library. I loaded obj models. But i need to load fbx to animations. I cant try anything yet. Because i cant open it with notepad or hexeditor... I need to examine the file content. But i cant ...

Comment: Reverse-engineering formats is generally unpleasant, particularly so for model formats where any one example is unlikely to use all (or even most) of the format's features. Considering that FBX is a reasonably well-known format, I'm sure documentation and/or libraries exist (Google shows a few dozen, including [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736845/can-anyone-explain-the-fbx-format-for-me)).

Comment: Does it need to handle FBX? Because the [Open Asset Import library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) can work with lots of formats, but FBX isn't one of them. Maybe you can export your mesh to something that OAI can work with.

Comment: there are 2 FBX formats, binary and ascii. When you open the Binary on editor, the data is transformed to "readable" and you see ininteligible bullshit. If the file is ASCII, it is human readable. It depends of the fbx plugin options used to export the data. You can import it from the program (Max, Maya, MB, Mudbox, ...) and export it again setting the ASCII flag, so you can read it.

Answer (score 4):

Autodesk own FBX, it is free (but not open-source) and the necessary libraries are available [here](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=7478532). You will need to register to download them.

And FWIW, 30 seconds of net searching would have given you the result.  Also OpenGL has nothing to do with FBX.